# How use renderer in XXX_PAGE_FORM.XML magento2,

Tags: magento2

string
                    entity
                    Image
                    1
                    true
                    fileUploader
                    ui/form/element/uploader/uploader
                    CNAME_MNAME/image-preview
                    false

How use Renderer it give error, Where i am wrong?